# permissions for SugarCRM in /var/www/html/

Tags: permissions, apache2, software-installation, configuration

I downloaded SugarCRM community edition, unzipped and moved it, with sudo, to `/var/www/html/` but keep getting errors when navigating to `http://dur.bounceme.net/sugar` or `localhost/sugar` (I renamed the directory `sugar` from `SugarCE-Full-6.5.16`).

```
System Check Acceptance     SugarCRM
Help

Errors have been detected during compatibility check. In order for your SugarCRM Installation to function properly, please take the proper steps to address the issues listed below and either press the recheck button, or try installing again.
Component   Status
Writable SugarCRM Configuration File (config.php)   The config file exists but is not writeable. Please take the necessary steps to make the file writeable. Depending on your Operating system, this might require you to change the permissions by running chmod 766, or to right click on the filename to access the properties and uncheck the read only option.
    The config override file exists but is not writeable. Please take the necessary steps to make the file writeable. Depending on your Operating system, this might require you to change the permissions by running chmod 766, or to right click on the filename to access the properties and uncheck the read only option.
Writeable Custom Directory  The Custom Directory exists but is not writeable. You may have to change permissions on it (chmod 766) or right click on it and uncheck the read only option, depending on your Operating System. Please take the needed steps to make the file writeable.
Writable Cache Sub-Directories  The files or directories listed below are not writeable or are missing and cannot be created. Depending on your Operating System, correcting this may require you to change permissions on the files or parent directory (chmod 755), or to right click on the parent directory and uncheck the 'read only' option and apply it to all subfolders.
Please fix the following files or directories before proceeding:
/var/www/html/sugar/cache/
/var/www/html/sugar/cache/images
/var/www/html/sugar/cache/layout
/var/www/html/sugar/cache/pdf
/var/www/html/sugar/cache/xml
Writable Modules Sub-Directories and Files  Warning: Not Writable
Please fix the following module directories and the files under them before proceeding:
/modules
Writable Upload Directory   Warning: Not Writable
Location of your PHP configuration file (php.ini):
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

I'm going through the permissions, but have already tried to fix the files and directories as per the message.

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/209547/163331

Comment: Related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allowed the install to proceeed:

```
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www
sudo chmod g+s -R /var/www
```

Comments and explanations welcome.

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/209547/45156)