# Wordpress Could not create directory

Tags: server, 14.04, wordpress

I am trying to install a plugin for Wordpress on Ubuntu 14.04 Server but it keeps failing. I assume it is a rights issue because of a directory not being able to create. This is my last ditch effort I have Googled and looked all I could but nothing has worked. Here is the error it happens on any plugin:

Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/syntaxhighlighter.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not create directory.

Comment: unzip the file, `sudo cp -R syntaxhighlighter /var/www/wp-content/plugins`. If you are not working on the command line, you will have to file a bug report against the graphical tool you are using to manage WP.

Comment: I have it copied into the right directory but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You have a permissions problem of some directory somewhere. See the first link I have you and be more specific on what you are doing to generate this error message. What command did you run from where to get what error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct and proper method would be to correct the permissions as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162866/correct-permissions-for-var-www-and-wordpress/487803#487803).

However to test you can always set the permissions on the entire wp-content/ directory to 777. Obviously this is a massive security risk and you shouldn't leave your directories like that.

[See here for the dangers of 777](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#The_dangers_of_777).