# Permissions issue Ubuntu 18.04 LTS LAMP Wordpress

Tags: permissions, apache2, wordpress

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a LAMP installation. I then install Wordpress 4.9.8 and the default sample website comes up in a browser.  I tried to delete a theme that came with WP 4.9.8 and got a message about enabling FTP.  I edited wp_config to force the "direct" method of access.

However, now I get an error message saying the deletion failed.

I'm sure I have a rights issue, but cannot figure out how to go about fixing that.

I'd appreciate help.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct permissions for /var/www and wordpress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162866/correct-permissions-for-var-www-and-wordpress)

Comment: You should always try to search for a related question before you post a question of your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up sftp to login into server with file zilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024194/setting-up-sftp-to-login-into-server-with-file-zilla)